# Force authentication to use sssd not nslcd

Tags: centos, authentication, sssd

What I did was:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/authconfig
        USESSSDAUTH=yes
        USESSSD=yes
        FORCELEGACY=no
```

Then:

```
authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablelocauthorize --update
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver="ipa.example.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --enablerfc2307bis --enableldaptls --update
authconfig --enablemkhomedir --enablecachecreds --update
authconfig --enablekrb5 --krb5kdc="ipa.example.com" --krb5adminserver="ipa.example.com" --krb5realm="EXAMPLE.COM" --update
authconfig --enablekrb5kdcdns --enablekrb5realmdns --update
```

after that I have added

```
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
```

to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

For some unknown reason, the server still using nslcd to authentication.
If am inside root user and trying to

```
su - LDAPuser
```

it works.
However, when I am inside normal user (local user), and I am trying to su into LDAP user, I am getting:

```
su: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
```

by looking at

```
systemctl status nslcd -l
Jul 24 13:18:21 server2.example.com nslcd[74273]: [482a97] <group/member="shaked"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Resource temporarily unavailable
Jul 24 13:18:25 server2.example.com nslcd[74273]: [63b9ea] <group/member="root"> no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

^^^ "shaked" is my local user

```
systemctl status sssd -l
```

^^^ doesn't give any errors

```
The content of /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
hosts:      files dns
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss
netgroup:   files sss ldap
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files sss ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

My OS is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Stop & disable nslcd:

```
systemctl stop nslcd
systemctl disable nslcd
```

Rerun authconfig but this time try to use all options on the same line and use --disableldapauth instead of --enableldapauth:

```
authconfig --enablelocauthorize --enableldap --disableldapauth --ldapserver="ipa.example.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --enablerfc2307bis --enableldaptls --enablemkhomedir --enablecachecreds --enablekrb5 --krb5kdc="ipa.example.com" --krb5adminserver="ipa.example.com" --krb5realm="EXAMPLE.COM" --enablekrb5kdcdns --enablekrb5realmdns --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --update
```